# How to split a file of 5000 lines in several files of 200 lines each with Perl?

Tags: perl

I've a file of 5000 lines and I want several files of 200 lines each, and I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $targetfile = '200_lines.txt';
my $filename = '5000_lines.txt';

open ( my $DATA, '<', $filename )  or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

while ( my $line = <$DATA> ) {
  my $counter++; 

  open (my $FILE, '>>', $targetfile ) or die "Could not open file '$targetfile': $!";
  print $FILE $line;
  close $FILE;
  if ( $counter % 200 == 0
    if ($. % 200 == 0) { 
      $targetfile =~ s/200/$counter/;
    }
}
```

My `$counter` variable still at 1. I don't know why. So I got just one file named `200_lines.txt` with 5000 lines.

Comment: `$counter` is local to the `while` block. Did you mean to declare it outside of the block?

Comment: I try  to do a stepper like : `(my $i = 200; $i <= 6000; $i += 200)`  for changing  the names of the files each 200 lines. If I put `$counter` outside the `while` the still as 1

Comment: The code in the question has some serious syntactical errors. Could you show us the *real* code?

Comment: If you're running Perl, you're probably on Unix, and there's a command for that.  Try `split -l 200 < 5000_lines.txt > 200_lines.txt`

Comment: With *Unix* taken very broadly - e.g. Cygwin has `split` as well.

Comment: I understood my `$counter++;` is not placed well because the loop `while` resset it to 0 each times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` to generate new filenames after every 200 lines and use `$.` to keep track of line numbers in the file.

The below script will generate smaller chunks of files from the larger file with 200 lines each.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $rfh,'<','file_5000' or die "unable to open file : $! \n";

my $filecount=0;
my $wfh;
while(<$rfh>){
    if(($.-1) % 200 == 0){
           close($wfh) if($wfh);
           open($wfh, '>', sprintf("file%02d", ++$filecount)) or die $!;
        }
   print $wfh "$_";
}
close($rfh);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed! Thank  you for this!

Answer (score 2):

- `$counter` is scoped within your while block. So it is reset each iteration.
- You don't really need to do it like that, as you can test `$.` for the current line number
- don't call your filehandle `$DATA`. There's a special filehandle called `<DATA>`.

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $input,  '<', '5000_lines.txt' ) or die $!;
open( my $output, '>', '200_lines.txt' )  or die $!;

while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    unless ( $. % 200 ) {
        close($output);
        open( $output, '>', int( $. / 200 + 2) . "00_lines.txt" ) or die $!;
    }
    print {$output} $line;
}
close($input);
close($output);
```

This creates files:

```
200_lines.txt
400_lines.txt
600_lines.txt
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of errors in your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Creating a file with 5000 lines
my $filename = '5000_lines.txt';
open ( $DATA, '>', $filename )  or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";

for (my $i=0;$i<5000;$i++){
    print $DATA "$i\n";
}
close ( $DATA);


my $targetfile = '200_lines.txt';

open ( my $DATA, '<', $filename )  or die "Could not open file '$filename': $!";
my $counter = 0;
my $num = 0;
my $flag = 1;
while ( my $line = <$DATA> ) {
      if ($flag == 1){
          open (FILE, '>', $targetfile.'_'.$num ) or die "Could not open file '$targetfile.'_'.$num': $!";
      }
      print FILE $line;
      $flag=0;
      if ( $counter % 200 == 0){
           $num = $counter/200;
           close FILE;
           $flag=1
       }
      $counter++; 
}
close (FILE);
```

It will break the large file into smaller chunks of 200 lines each.

Comment: Would strongly suggest not using `DATA` as that's a special case for filenames. And generally speaking, using lexical filehandles.

Comment: +1, Yeah, I realized and changed that in the code. I used it to be consistent with the OP's original post.